# url change in google maps and page not refresh, why?

Tags: google-maps, url

URL in Google maps is something like this:

`https://www.google.com/maps/@numbers`

I know if url change after `#` web page no need to refresh( am i wrong?)

but in this case(change url after `@`), web page still not refresh.
How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put a valid latitude,longitude in your URL. Also, you need to put the character **z** after your longitude.

Sample url can be this: https://www.google.com/maps/@34.0204989,-118.4117325,10z